# RailsTutorial: diff-lcs-1.1.3 can not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, railstutorial.org

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

i was playing around with that tutorial and when executing:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

i get this:

```
Could not find diff-lcs-1.1.3 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
```

when running bundle show:

```
...
* builder (3.0.0)
* bundler (1.1.rc)
* diff-lcs (1.1.3)
* erubis (2.7.0)
* hike (1.2.1)
...
```

and i made sure its installed....
i can find it in the system etc....

any ideas? never really looked into ruby so that might be why i am failing already, haha

Comment: I'm not certain that this is necessarily an answer to this problem, but I had this error message and added `bundle exec` to the beginning of my command, which worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `bundle install` first as mentioned in the error message above

Run `bundle install` or `bundle install --without production` first

and then run `rails g rspec:install`

I highly recommend you check:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-gemfile_rspec

and run `bundle install`.

I also wonder if you installed RVM successfully.

If you fail to install gems, I think you should go over the previous part again.